# you cannot access the CP with that account

Tags: control-panel, user-profile

New user has activated account but is getting this message when trying to log in: "you cannot access the CP with that account"

Comment: Did you gave him permission to CP access or associated him with Admin group?

Comment: Not sure - will check - do I need to?

Comment: Does it take time before a new user gets access to the CP?

Comment: Seems like a permissions problem. How did you create this user? Did you give them the ability to access the CP? Do you have different user groups?

Answer (score 2):

If a user gets that message when logging in, then it means they haven't been assigned the ["Access the CP"](https://craftcms.com/docs/users#permissions) permissions in the Control Panel, either directly or through a [User Group](https://craftcms.com/docs/users#user-groups) that they belong to.